# Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN" in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I want to try display a chart in highcharts that is a heatmap chart.
it works correctly when i have a little data but when i have large amount that is destroyed.

```
 chart: {
   type: 'heatmap',
   marginTop: 40,
   marginBottom: 80,
   plotBorderWidth: 1,
   height: 600
}
```

I saved that in 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fuy98np/).

Can anybody help me to adjust this code for large amounts of data?

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: I tested your fiddle on my machine and it doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in the data set :

```
...
[141141, 12, 0], // line 219 I think it's 141 not 141141
...
[4577, 17, 0], // line 1165
...
[6106, 17, 0], // line 1253
...
[8787, 17, 1], // line 1263
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLnza5te/)